# How correctly redirect to error page? php

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

How I can redirect to my error page?

My directory structure:

[image]

Inside .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Index.php?controller=Main&action=error
```

I don't know how correctly to tell, but it redirects me to ../ back one level.., in xampp ../ will be Index file...And show:
[image]

I want on 404 error redirect to Index.

I try in .htaccess file add this line:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 Index.php?controller=Main&action=error
```

but without / flash its show text like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter an absolute URI, like `ErrorDocument 404 /Index.php?controller=Main&action=error`

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: but with ErrorDocument 404 /Index.php?controller=Main&action=error this redirects me back one level, but my index file is in root where is .htaccess file. I can use this: ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8080/flowers/Index.php?controller=Main&action=error, but I think better without link of web page

Comment: I don't see the problem, use an ABSOLUTE PATH: `ErrorDocument 404 /flowers/Index.php?controller=Main&action=error`